# SPA from within component and clicking on nav appends to the url VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

I am creating a SPA in VueJS and when I click the nav links, they take me to the appropriate id's within the page. I have a component for my Privacy page. When one goes to the menu to go back to any router-link, it appends the name of the link to the existing url. I am confused on how to handle this so as to include a slash in the url. For example. I am in my main page and I click on the privacy link in the footer, it takes me to the privacy page as one would expect. However, when I click on the menu link, say... for example the services link, when I hover over the link, I can see it wants to go to a url such as: https://rrspark.com/Privacy#services
As you can see this is an erroneous url as I want https://rrspark.com/#services which is one of my routes. I am 100% convinced I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. Below is my code.

Component Folder
Nav.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="/">
          <span class="first-r">R</span>
          <span class="second-r">R</span>
          <span class="spark">Spark</span>
        </a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarResponsive"
          aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          Menu
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" v-for="(linkObj, ind) in navList" :key="ind">
              <a
                class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger hashed-menu-item"
                :href="linkObj.path"
                v-if="linkObj.path.indexOf('#') === 0"
              >{{linkObj.name}}</a>
              <router-link
                class="nav-link"
                js-scroll-trigger
                v-else
                :to="linkObj.path"
              >{{linkObj.name }}</router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    navList: [
      {
        name: "Services",
        path: "#services"
      },
      {
        name: "Portfolio",
        path: "#portfolio"
      },
      {
        name: "About",
        path: "#about"
      },
      {
        name: "Team",
        path: "#team"
      },
      {
        name: "Contact",
        path: "#contact"
      }
    ]
  })
};
</script>
<style lang="">
</style>
```

Root 
router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';


Vue.use(VueRouter);

function load(componentName) {
    return () => import(`@/components/${componentName}`);
}

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: load('Home')
        }
        ,
        {
            path: '/services',
            name: 'Services',
            component: load('Services')
        },
        {
            path: '/portfolio',
            name: 'Portfolio',
            component: load('Portfolio')
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'About',
            component: load('About')
        },
        {
            path: '/team',
            name: 'Team',
            component: load('Team')
        },
        {
            path: '/contact',
            name: 'Contact',
            component: load('Contact')
        },
        {
            path: '/privacy',
            name: 'Privacy',
            component: load('Privacy')
        },
        {
            path: '/success',
            name: 'Success',
            component: load('Success')
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            name: '404',
            component: load('404')
        }
    ]
});

export default router;
```

Components folder

```
<template>
  <div id="#privacy">
    <Nav></Nav>
    <div class="header-holder mb-4">
      <a class="home-link float-left font-italic" href="/">
        <span class="first-r">R</span>
        <span class="second-r">R</span>
        <span class="spark">Spark</span>
      </a>
      <h1 id="traL1" data-token="translatable.traL1" class="pt-5 text-white">RR Spark Privacy Policy</h1>
      <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center p-3">
        <p class="place-left" id="traL3" data-token="translatable.traL3">Last updated: March 8 2020</p>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL4" data-token="translatable.traL4">
          RR Spark operates https://www.rrspark.com (the "Site"). This page
          informs you of our policies regarding the collection, use and
          disclosure of Personal Information we receive from users of the
          Site.
        </p>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL5" data-token="translatable.traL5">
          We use your Personal Information only for providing and improving
          the Site. By using the Site, you agree to the collection and use of
          information in accordance with this policy.
        </p>
        <h3
          class="place-left"
          id="traL6"
          data-token="translatable.traL6"
        >Information Collection And Use</h3>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL7" data-token="translatable.traL7">
          While using our Site, we may ask you to provide us with certain
          personally identifiable information that can be used to contact or
          identify you. Personally identifiable information may include, but
          is not limited to your name ("Personal Information").
        </p>
        <h3 class="place-left" id="traL8" data-token="translatable.traL8">Log Data</h3>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL9" data-token="translatable.traL9">
          Like many site operators, we collect information that your browser
          sends whenever you visit our Site ("Log Data").
          This Log Data may include information such as your computer's
          Internet Protocol ("IP") address, browser type, browser version, the
          pages of our Site that you visit, the time and date of your visit,
          the time spent on those pages and other statistics.
          In addition, we may use third party services such as Google
          Analytics that collect, monitor and analyze data from users visiting
          this site.
        </p>
        <h3 class="place-left" id="traL12" data-token="translatable.traL12">Communications</h3>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL13" data-token="translatable.traL13">
          We may use your Personal Information to contact you with
          newsletters, marketing or promotional materials and other
          information that we may feel useful for those visiting the site.
        </p>
        <h3 class="place-left" id="traL14" data-token="translatable.traL14">Cookies</h3>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL15" data-token="translatable.traL15">
          Cookies are files with small amount of data, which may include an
          anonymous unique identifier. Cookies are sent to your browser from a
          web site and stored on your computer's hard drive.
        </p>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL16" data-token="translatable.traL16">
          Like many sites, we use "cookies" to collect information. You can
          instruct your browser to refuse all cookies or to indicate when a
          cookie is being sent. However, if you do not accept cookies, you may
          not be able to use some portions of our Site.
        </p>
        <h3 class="place-left" id="traL17" data-token="translatable.traL17">Security</h3>
        <p class="place-left" id="traL17a" data-token="translatable.traL17a">
          The security of your Personal Information is important to us, but
          remember that no method of transmission over the Internet, or method
          of electronic storage, is 100% secure. While we strive to use
          commercially acceptable means to protect your Personal Information,
          we cannot guarantee its absolute security.
        </p>
        <h3
          class="place-left"
          id="traL18"
          data-token="translatable.traL18"
        >Changes to this Privacy Policy</h3>
        <p class="place-left">
          This Privacy Policy is effective as of (October 1st 2019) and will
          remain in effect except with respect to any changes in its
          provisions in the future, which will be in effect immediately after
          being posted on this page.
        </p>
        <p class="place-left">
          We reserve the right to update or change our Privacy Policy at any
          time and you should check this Privacy Policy periodically. Your
          continued use of the Service after we post any modifications to the
          Privacy Policy on this page will constitute your acknowledgment of
          the modifications and your consent to abide and be bound by the
          modified Privacy Policy.
        </p>
        <p class="place-left">
          If we make any material changes to this Privacy Policy, we will post
          that information here.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Footer from "./Footer";
export default {
  components: {
    Nav,
    Footer
  }
};
</script>
<style lang="sass">
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from '../router';
import VueResource from "vue-resource"
import './assets/css/style.css'
import './assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import NotFound from './components/404';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(NotFound);


new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

    </style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Footer.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; RR Spark 2020</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="########" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="#######" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a href="########" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="mt-3 text-white">Phone: ###-###-####</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <router-link :to="'/Privacy'">Privacy Policy</router-link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {};
</script>
<style lang="sass">

</style>
```

Comment: It's appending to whatever is the current route because of how you're creating the links.  You're in history mode so you shouldn't have `#` in your links unless your navigating to a section inside a page.  My suggestion is to use `router-link`s, give it the name of the route you want and let it handle creating the correct url for you.

Comment: That is right, all my links in my navbar are linking to sections(id's) in my spa whereas the Privacy page in a component outside of the SPA. I am unclear on what to do. Thank you.